# How to fix "Undefined function or variable" error in this script?

Tags: matlab, structure

I'm implementing the following function to query for all college entries whose name is 'Texas':

```
function [] = queryHandler(structName, fieldName, fieldValue)

% query for college names



for i = 1:1:length(structName.fieldName)
    if strcmp(structName(i).fieldName, fieldValue)
        if strcmp(fieldName, 'name')
            foundNames(i) = structName(i);
        elseif strcmp(fieldName, 'nickName')
            foundnickNames(i) = structName(i);
        elseif strcmp(fieldName, 'location')
            foundLoactions(i) = structName(i);

    end
end

if strcmp(fieldName, 'name')
    foundNames
elseif strcmp(fieldName, 'nickName')
    foundnickNames
elseif strcmp(fieldName, 'location')
    foundLocations
end
end
```

Here is the main script:

```
%collegeDatabase main test script
clc
clear


%preallocation for speed
names = {'Kansas', 'KSU', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas', 'Alabama', 'LSU', 'Mizzou', 'Stanford', 'Auburn', 'Oregon'};
nickNames = {'Jayhawks', 'Wildcats', 'Sooners', 'Longhorns', 'Crimson Tide', 'Tigers', 'Tigers', 'Cardinals', 'Tigers', 'Ducks'};
locations = {'Kansas', 'Kansas', 'Oklahoma', 'Texas', 'Alabama', 'Louisiana', 'Missouri', 'California', 'Alabama', 'Oregon'};

college(10).name = {' '};
college(10).nickName = {' '};
college(10).location = {' '};

%creation of structure for college names, nicknames, loactions

for i = 1:length(names)
    college(i).name = names(i);
    college(i).nickName = nickNames(i);
    college(i).loaction = locations(i);
end

queryHandler(college, name, Texas)
```

I am trying to get these inputs to search for college(i).name is 'Texas' in the database. What do I have to do with the inputs here to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, in the main script you should probably be calling `queryHandler(college, 'name', 'Texas')`.

Second, in your function, you should change all of your `structName(i).fieldName` calls to `structName(i).(fieldName)`.

Finally, in your for loop, you should be going up to `structName(0).(fieldName)`. Your struct itself does not have an element `fieldName`, but each individual element does.